# How do I calculate the electrical conductivty of arbitrary semi-metal?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics

Assume that I have an Hamiltonian $$H=\sum_{k,\sigma}a^\dagger_k E(k)a_k$$ where $E$ is the dispersion relation with gap closing at some points. I want to calculate the conductivity of this system. To do so first I have to apply an external electromagnetic field.

Under external electromagnetic field how would this $H$ be modified.